# Sliding image puzzle game - image not centered when game window is resized

Tags: python, pygame

I am working on a sliding puzzle game, but when I adjust the game window of the game the image with tiles is stock on the left side and it cannot go with center. I borrowed this code from GitHub. I am new with python and starting to explore new things. I want to learn more in python and thank you in advance. These are the codes:

import pygame as pg
import os.path
import random
import sys

class PuzzlerGame():
def **init**(self):
global BASICFONT

```
    window_width = 1380
    # window_width  =700
    window_height = 770

    self.tile_width = 150
    # self.tile_width = 75
    self.tile_height = 150
    # self.tile_height = 75

    self.coloumn = 4
    self.rows = 4

    self.img_list = [0, "image1.jpg", "image2.jpg", "image3.jpg", "image4.jpg",
                     "image5.jpg", "image6.jpg", "image7.jpg", "image8.jpg",
                     "image9.jpg", "image10.jpg", ]

    self.empty_tile = (3, 3)
    global emptyc, emptyr
    emptyc, emptyr = 3, 3

    self.color = (255, 130, 130)
    # white = (215,215,215)
    self.yellow = (255, 255, 0)
    self.red = (200, 15, 15)
    self.black = (0, 0, 0)

    self.tiles = {}

    pg.init()
    self.gameWindow = pg.display.set_mode((window_width, window_height))
    # pg.display.set_caption("Puzzler")
    pg.display.set_caption("Fun City slide puzzle")

    # self.gameWindow.fill(white)
    self.gameWindow.fill(self.red)
    pg.display.update()

    if (os.path.isfile('level.txt')):
        lfile = open('level.txt', 'r')
        # print(storefile)
        self.level = int(lfile.read())
        # self.level=str(lfile.read())
        # print(self.highscore)
        lfile.close()
    else:
        self.level = 1

    # self.intro()
    self.start(1)

def message(self, v1, u1, text):
    rect_w = 70
    rect_h = 70

    font = pg.font.SysFont('comicsansms', 25)
    TextSurf = font.render(text, True, self.black)
    TextRect = TextSurf.get_rect()
    TextRect.center = ((v1 * rect_w + ((rect_w - 3) / 2)),
                       (u1 * rect_h + (rect_h / 2)))

    self.gameWindow.blit(TextSurf, TextRect)
    pg.display.update()

def buttons(self, text):

    # rect_w = 70
    rect_w = 180
    # rect_h = 70
    rect_h = 180
    color = self.color

    # additional button

    mouse_pos = pg.mouse.get_pos()
    click = pg.mouse.get_pressed()

    if (self.v * rect_w + rect_w - 3 > mouse_pos[0] > self.v * rect_w
            and self.u * rect_h + rect_h - 3 > mouse_pos[1] > self.u * rect_h):
        if int(text) <= self.level:
            # if str(text)<=self.level:
            color = (255, 30, 30)
            if click[0] == 1:
                self.start(int(text))
        else:
            pass

    pg.draw.rect(self.gameWindow, color, [self.v * rect_w, self.u * rect_h,
                                          rect_w - 100, rect_h - 3])
    self.message(self.v, self.u, text)
    # self.message(text)
    pg.display.update()

def intro(self):

    # additional for button
    # NEW_SURF, NEW_RECT = self.makeText("New game", self.yellow, window_width - 120, window_height - 90)

    while True:

        self.v = 4
        self.u = 5

        for event in pg.event.get():

            if event.type == pg.QUIT:
                pg.quit()
                sys.exit()

        for rec in range(1, 2):  # Level Number showing

            # self.labels(300, 430, "Tap to Start", (0, 0, 255))
            # self.buttons(str(rec))
            # self.labels()
            # self.message(self.v,self.u,str(rec))

            self.v += 1

            if self.v == 8:
                self.v = 4
                self.u += 1

#############################################################################

def labels(self, v1, u1, text, color, size=20):
    font = pg.font.SysFont('comicsansms', size)
    TextSurf = font.render(text, True, color)
    TextRect = TextSurf.get_rect()
    # print(TextRect)
    TextRect.center = (v1, u1)

    self.gameWindow.blit(TextSurf, TextRect)
    pg.display.update()

def check(self):

    global game_over

    j, k = 0, 0
    tag_list = []

    for i in range(1, 17):
        # print("checking ",i,tiles[(j,k)])

        tag = "tag" + str(i)
        # print(tag,j,k)

        if self.tiles[(j, k)][1] == tag:
            tag_list.append(tag)
            j += 1
            if j > 3:
                k += 1
                j = 0

        else:
            break

    if i == 16:
        print("GAME FINISHED")
        game_over = True

def shift(self, c, r):
    global emptyc, emptyr
    rect_color = (255, 255, 255)  # the square for suffling
    # rect_color = (0,0,0)
    self.gameWindow.blit(
        self.tiles[(c, r)][0],
        (emptyc * self.tile_width, emptyr * self.tile_height))

    '''pg.draw.rect(gameWindow,black,[c*tile_width,r*tile_height,
                              tile_width-1,tile_height-1])'''

    self.gameWindow.blit(
        self.tiles[self.empty_tile][0],
        (c * self.tile_width, r * self.tile_height))

    # state[(emptyc, emptyr)] = state[(c, r)]
    # state[(c, r)] = empty_tile

    temp = self.tiles[(c, r)]
    # print(temp,c,r)

    self.tiles[(c, r)] = self.tiles[(emptyc, emptyr)]
    self.tiles[(emptyc, emptyr)] = temp

    emptyc, emptyr = c, r

    # tiles[(emptyc, emptyr)].fill(black)
    pg.draw.rect(self.gameWindow, rect_color, [c * self.tile_width, r * self.tile_height,
                                               self.tile_width - 1, self.tile_height - 1])

    self.empty_tile = (emptyc, emptyr)

    # empty_tile.fill(0,0,0)
    pg.display.flip()

def shuffle(self):
    global emptyc, emptyr
    # keep track of last shuffling direction to avoid "undo" shuffle moves
    last_r = 0
    for i in range(100):
        # slow down shuffling for visual effect
        pg.time.delay(50)
        while True:
            # pick a random direction and make a shuffling move
            # if that is possible in that direction
            r = random.randint(1, 4)
            if (last_r + r == 5):
                # don't undo the last shuffling move
                continue
            if r == 1 and (emptyc > 0):
                self.shift(emptyc - 1, emptyr)  # shift left
            elif r == 4 and (emptyc < self.coloumn - 1):
                self.shift(emptyc + 1, emptyr)  # shift right
            elif r == 2 and (emptyr > 0):
                self.shift(emptyc, emptyr - 1)  # shift up
            elif r == 3 and (emptyr < self.rows - 1):
                self.shift(emptyc, emptyr + 1)  # shift down
            else:
                # the random shuffle move didn't fit in that direction
                continue
            last_r = r
            break  # a shuffling move was made

def start(self, l):

    f = 1
    imageX = 350
    imageY = 50
    global level, game_over
    game_over = False
    level = l
    img = self.img_list[level]
    self.image = pg.image.load("./Res/" + img)

    button = pg.image.load("./efx/" + "button.jpg")
    self.button = pg.image.load("./efx/" + "button.jpg")

    self.gameWindow.fill((190, 190, 190))  # color of the window
    for r in range(self.coloumn):

        for c in range(self.rows):

            tag = "tag" + str(f)

            tile = self.image.subsurface(c * self.tile_width, r * self.tile_height,
                                         self.tile_width - 1, self.tile_height - 1)
            f += 1
            self.tiles[(c, r)] = (tile, tag)

            if (c, r) == self.empty_tile:
                pg.draw.rect(self.gameWindow, (255, 255, 255),
                             # pg.draw.rect(self.gameWindow,(260,260,260),
                             [c * self.tile_width, r * self.tile_height,
                              self.tile_width - 1, self.tile_height - 1])#width and height of the white tile
                break

            self.gameWindow.blit(tile, (c * self.tile_width, r * self.tile_height)) # uploading the image through the window
            #self.gameWindow.blit(tile,(imageX,imageY))
            pg.display.update()
            # print(tile)

    # print(tiles)
    # text = "Level "+str(level)
    text = "Have fun!"
    self.labels(350, 625, text, (0, 0, 255))
    # self.labels(300,625,"Click to start Game",(0,0,255))
    self.labels(700, 300, "Tap to start Game", (0, 0, 255))
    self.gameWindow.blit(button, (640, 180))

    pg.display.update()

    self.gameloop()

def gameloop(self):

    started = False
    show_sol = False

    global level
    # self.gameWindow.fill((190,190,190),(150,610,300,40))

    while True:

        if game_over:
            self.labels(300, 300, "Good job well played", (255, 100, 30), 50)
            # self.labels(300,625,"Click to next Level",(0,0,255))

        for event in pg.event.get():

            # print(event)
            if event.type == pg.QUIT:
                pg.quit()
                sys.exit()

            if event.type == pg.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                # print(event.type)
                # print(event.dict)
                # shuffle()

                if not started:
                    self.shuffle()
                    self.gameWindow.fill((190, 190, 190), (150, 610, 300, 40))
                    # self.labels(300,625,"Right click to see Solution",(0,0,255))
                    started = True

                if game_over:
                    level += 1
                    # self.labels(300,300,"Good job well played",(255,100,30),50)
                    # self.labels(300,625,"Click to next Level",(0,0,255))
                    if self.level < level:
                        self.level += 1
                        file = open("level.txt", "w")
                        file.write(str(self.level))
                        file.close()
                    self.start(level)

                if event.dict['button'] == 1:
                    mouse_pos = pg.mouse.get_pos()

                    c = mouse_pos[0] // self.tile_width
                    r = mouse_pos[1] // self.tile_height

                    # print("dot posn",emptyc,emptyr)
                    # print("mouse posn",c,r)

                    if c == emptyc and r == emptyr:
                        continue
                    elif c == emptyc and (r == emptyr - 1 or r == emptyr + 1):
                        self.shift(c, r)
                        self.check()
                    elif r == emptyr and (c == emptyc - 1 or c == emptyc + 1):
                        self.shift(c, r)
                        self.check()
                    # print(c,r)

                elif event.dict['button'] == 3:
                    saved_image = self.gameWindow.copy()
                    # print(saved_image)
                    # gameWindow.fill(255,255,255)
                    self.gameWindow.blit(self.image, (0, 0))
                    pg.display.flip()
                    show_sol = True

            elif show_sol and (event.type == pg.MOUSEBUTTONUP):
                # stop showing the solution
                self.gameWindow.blit(saved_image, (0, 0))
                pg.display.flip()
                show_sol = False
```

if **name** == "**main**":
PuzzlerGame()

Comment: When you are completely new in python, start with a basic tutorial, rather than a complete application. You cannot ask questions of the kind *"Please help, I want to learn python"* here.

Comment: Please read [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question)

Answer (score 0):

The *dest* argument of [`pygame.Surface.blit()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.blit) can also be a rectangle. To center an image on the screen get the bounding rectangle of the image with [`pygame.Surface.get_rect`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.get_rect). Set the center of the rectangle by the center of the screen. Use the rectangle to `blit` the image:

```py
game_window_rect = self.gameWindow.get_rect()
dest_rect = saved_image.get_rect(center = game_window_rect.center)
self.gameWindow.blit(saved_image, dest_rect)
```

Comment: Hi @Rabbid can I ask in which part should I add this syntax, I am noob with my python and starting only new things. Because what happening is the slide puzzle game will shuffle but its stock on the left side of the game window, Thanks